How public does it have to be for public intoxication?
There is a story of the arrest and charging of someone who commented on police action occurring in public from their private balcony with public intoxication.  The charges were dropped, and a lawsuit is ongoing suing the police, but it raises the question of exactly what makes something public.
Exactly what makes the state of intoxication "public" for the purposes of public intoxication laws?
The event occurred in Newport, Kentucky but answers for any jurisdiction worldwide would be of interest.

KRS 525.010 defines "public place" as:

a place to which the public or a substantial group of persons has access and includes but is not limited to highways, transportation facilities, schools, places of amusements, parks, places of business, playgrounds, and hallways, lobbies, and other portions of apartment houses and hotels not constituting rooms or apartments designed for actual residence. An act is deemed to occur in a public place if it produces its offensive or proscribed consequences in a public place.


So a room behind a door with a big sign “authorised personnel only” may not be open to the public (you and i are not allowed to enter), but it counts legally as a public space FFT or this law. And a hotel room currently not rented out or rented out to someone else is not a public space.

So, is the balcony a public place in the context or not? The answer doesn't elaborate on that. Leaving such things to the layman reader's interpretation makes the answer vague. It may be obvious to the lauded experts of this community but not to the former public.

I can see arguments in either direction, but the fact that the charges were dismissed with prejudice strongly suggests that the answer is no.

@MindwinRememberMonica I can easily imagine that a street-facing balcony might be considered public, while a balcony facing a private yard is not. It might not matter for public intoxication, but consider public nudity statutes.

@barmar I'd agree. The last sentence of the definition seems to substantially broaden the definition to the point where even the interior of your home might be a public place if you're doing something that produces "offensive consequences" on the sidewalk.

@bdb484 Indeed. If you expose yourself in by a street-facing window, that would likely be an offense.

I'd like to see this reasoning on the answer if possible, since comments are volatile and can disappear at anytime. Because for a decade or more, people told me that a link or quote-only answer was of poor quality.

@MindwinRememberMonica That would be a bit speculative, in my opinion. I'm sure there are court decisions analyzing this question, but I haven't read them and therefore am not in a position to comment on them.

@bdb484 A judge could dismiss a case for different reasons. In this case  because the accused was sober or had only one drink, so public or not didn’t matter.
